# Remove wrapper tag

Tags: jquery, css

This is my code
how to remove wrapper span tag (Don't remove text)

```
  <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span>Removce wraper tag</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      <li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I post here @Michael Dautermann

Comment: No id, no class, no nothing to refer to on jQuery

Comment: @hun - You have to show that you have at least tried to solve this yourself.  The code they are asking for is your **attempts** or some code that you have that is throwing errors.  Simply **asking people to write your code**  is [not how we do things around here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553).

Comment: @thisMayhem: There are always structural selectors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right, but he'll have a harder time understanding it if he can't even select the element he wants. Just saying..

Comment: I dont know jQuery well, i did try several time, but i coudnt remove span tag but dont delete content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) for that. Just use any selector that will identify the `span`, and then call `unwrap`. For instance, if you give the `span` an ID (this is just an example), then:

```
$("#theid").unwrap();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/erozox) | [source](http://jsbin.com/erozox/edit)

Comment: Thanks, but i cant add any class or ID, This is pinnacle cart help me, I am not jQuery expert

Comment: @Hunter: The only expertise required beyond what I've given you above is to come up with a CSS selector that will match the span. In your example, for instance, `$("ul > li > ul > li > a > span")...` would also work: http://jsbin.com/erozox/2 But I'd recommend finding some element you can use as the root of that, so you don't affect other matching `span` elements on the page. There's usually a way to find something to anchor it. Separately: "I am not an expert" isn't an excuse for not trying something. In fact, saying "I am not an expert" is a great way to *start developing expertise*.